# How to correctly write boolean expression involving python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean

I have two python dictionary structures in which I am looking up for a specific key. But python evaluates it to `None` if the value is `0` . I am using Python2.7

```
A = {'distribution_1':{'mu':0.0,'sigma':0.5}}
B = {'distribution_1':{'sigma':0.1}}
x = A.get('mu') or B.get('mu') # This evaluates to None, expected 0.0
```

whereas

```
A = {'distribution_1':{'mu':0.1,'sigma':0.5}}
B = {'distribution_1':{'sigma':0.1}}
x = A.get('mu') or B.get('mu') # This evaluates to 0.1
```

To set the context, these two dictionaries contain parameters for probability distributions

Comment: `print A["distribution_1"].get('mu') #or 
print B["distribution_1"].get('mu') 
` ?

Comment: Just FYI getting a key from a dictionary by default only accesses that dictionary's keys, it does not look for the requested key in any values in that dictionary that may or may not be dictinaries. If you check the dictionary from your first example: `A.keys()` you'll se that it only has one key in it, `distribution_1`, so when you try to `get` anything else it returns `None`. If you have a dictionary as a value inside a dictionary, you have to access that dictionary as well, like Rakesh demonstrated: `A['distribution_1']['mu']` or `A.get('distribution_1',{}).get('mu')`

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, it is better using `A["distribution_1"].get('mu')` while *this also does not change the output*. It evaluates the first condition, and since it's `0` (or False) is evaluates the second condition which is `None`.

In the second case, it first evaluates `A.get('mu')` and since it is not `zero`, it will be returned.

Look at here:
**Case 1:**

```
A = {'mu':0.1}
B = {'sigma':0.5}
x = A.get('mu') or B.get('sigma')
print(x)
```

Output:

```
0.1
```

*it evaluates the first condition, and since it's `0.1`, this will be returned.*

**Case 2:**

```
A = {'mu':0.0}
B = {'sigma':0.5}
x = A.get('mu') or B.get('sigma')
print(x)
```

Output:

```
0.5
```

*it evaluates the first condition, and since it's `0` (or False), the second condition will be evaluated.*

---

**A possible solution** (if you want to get zero as answer):

```
A = {'mu':0.0}
B = {'sigma':0.5}
if 'mu' in A: 
    x = A.get('mu') 
else: 
    x = B.get('sigma')
# or more compact: x = [A.get('mu') if 'mu' in A else B.get('sigma')][0]
print(x)
```

Output:

```
0.0
```